# Can I do this when I define an enum?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, enums

Can I do this when I define an enum? I mean have a specific entry at the end with a value that is not the expected one?

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, countries) {
  kAustria = 101,
  kBelgium,
  kEngland,
  kFrance,
  kNONE = 200,
};
```

This enum will assign 101, 102, 103 and 104 to the four countries respectively and 200 to `kNONE`, that is what I want, right?

Will this work correctly?

and what about this? (just checking to see the possibilities)

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, countries) {
  kAustria = 101,
  kBelgium,
  kNONE = 200,
  kEngland = 103,
  kFrance,
};
```

Comment: Seriously.. despite being a valid question, it takes like 5 minutes to test whether or not it'll work.

Comment: Yes, but Xcode is a piece of crap and you never know if you will have problems with other aspects/uses of doing that. I was just checking if there was something surprise to be found in the future.

Comment: Not a code issue at all. OP cannot be bothered to test if `enum`s work in Xcode.

Comment: not everybody is so genius, so intelligent, so experienced and do smart as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a problem at all -

you can define specific values for individual constants in the enum definition.
Mixing specific and auto-generated values (i.e. the continuation the compiler will generate for you if you don't explicitly specify a value) will work just fine as well.

Here's a nice blog article explaining enums:
[Objective C Enum: How to Declare and Use Enumerated Types in Objective C](https://www.udemy.com/blog/objective-c-enum/)